# Add a global to the value of the previous tick, every tick

Tags: netlogo

I am working on a project that requires me to divide subsidies. I got two breeds, industries and the port. Now, I would like that each tick adds the subsidy to the previous amount instead of just picking the value of that particular tick. I got this:

```
to go
    if file-at-end? [ stop ]
  file-open "oil price.csv"
  set oil-price csv:from-row file-read-line
  file-open "co2 price.csv"
  set co2-price csv:from-row file-read-line
  file-open "electricity price.csv"
  set electricity-price csv:from-row file-read-line
  ;; model update goes here
  distribute-subsidies
  ask industries [update-profit]
if ticks >= 32 [stop]
  tick
end

to distribute-subsidies
 ask industries [set subsidy-industry (15000000 - 150000 * subsidy-to-port) / 25]
 ask ports [set subsidy-port 150000 * subsidy-to-port]
end
```

All help is welcome! Thanks in advance:)

Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a variable to store the subsidy. I think you are giving a subsidy to each industry and port. So you need `industries-own` and `ports-own` to define a variable for each turtle. Then you can simply add the new subsidy to the previous subsidy.

From your code, I believe you already have these variables. You haven't shown us the `own` statements. Replace your distribution procedure with:

```
to distribute-subsidies
 ask industries
 [ set subsidy-industry subsidy-industry + (15000000 - 150000 * subsidy-to-port) / 25
 ]
 ask ports
 [ set subsidy-port subsidy-port + 150000 * subsidy-to-port
 ]
end
```

Or, if you are worried about efficiency, calculate it once and add to all.

```
to distribute-subsidies
 let new-subsidy-industry (15000000 - 150000 * subsidy-to-port) / 25
 let new-port-subsidy 150000 * subsidy-to-port
 ask industries
 [ set subsidy-industry subsidy-industry + new-subsidy-industry
 ]
 ask ports
 [ set subsidy-port subsidy-port + new-port-subsidy
 ]
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked like a charm:)

Comment: @MaxGoessens - If Jen's answer has resolved your issue, please click the little check mark near the top of their answer to mark this question as closed.